# soap web service

Tags: iphone, xcode, parsing

I am parsing a soap web service for authentication but it is not returining any NSData so that I can writex xml parser for it.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
**
-(void)getAdvertisment
{
    NSString* soapMesasge=
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
      xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"   
      xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
      "<soap:Body>"
      "<GetAdvertisement xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" />"
      "</soap:Body>"
      "</soap:Envelope>"];**



    NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://codeexsolutions.com/HosService/ServiceHOSProvider.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString* msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMesasge length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetAdvertisement" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMesasge dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection)
    {
        webData =[[NSMutableData alloc]retain];
    }
    else
    {
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    }   

}
```

Comment: you can edit your own question if you like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [soap web service parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456212/soap-web-service-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection is an asynchronous method - have you implemented the rest of the delegate methods needed to actually listen for and retrieve the data?

You may wish to review the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

In your example above, webData will always be empty, it's up to you to populate it...